# How to call a class defined in the config

Tags: laravel

As the title suggests, I need to call a class.

Example config file within Laravel:

```
return [
    'user' => App\User::class
];
```

The problem I have is that I need to do run the non-static method and not sure how to do that.

i.e. `(new User())->getTable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this in your config file `example_config_file.php`:

```
return [
    'user' => App\User::class,
];
```

You can call it like this using the `new` command to create an instance of the `User` model:

```
$userClass = config('example_config_file.user');
$user = new $userClass();    // blank instance of User model
```

Or like this if you want to use Eloquent methods:

```
$userClass = config('example_config_file.user');
$user = $userClass::find(1);    // User model with id = 1
```

You can create a helper class and get any type of model like this:

```
class ModelHelper
{
    public static function getModel($type, $id = null)
    {
        $modelClass = config("example_config_file.$type");

        if($id) {
            return $modelClass::find($id);
        }

        return new $modelClass();
    }
}
```

Then in your code, whenever you need a user instance, call the helper class:

```
$user = ModelHelper::getModel('user');    // get a blank User model
$post = ModelHelper::getModel('post', 1); // get the post with id = 1
```

Comment: is there a nice way to gather all the classes from the config? rather than keep running the two lines that you have suggested... maybe using a custom class handler that returns `new $userClass(); `?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The point is to get the class name into a variable, and then use that variable to instantiate the class. There are plenty of ways you could do that, like creating a helper function that runs those lines, then you can just call the helper. It depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: My config has multiple models. They can be accessed via `config('my_config.models.user')`. The problem that I have is that I need to keep writing two lines. With helper, I need to write a full path. With a class, I would want to say something similar to: `myClass::getModel('user')->get()` or `myClass::getModel('user')->getTable()`